# CKEditor modified css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I got an issue when using ckeditor which is ckeditor change some css setting.

Original textarea: [Original textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9aZl.png)

Using ckeditor: [ckeditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nm26.png)

As you can see, the textarea field color become same as my background color.

Also, input text become `text-align:center`. It should be default as 'left' which same as the original one, doesn't it?

Here is my code,

html head:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Web Development</title>

<!--Font Awsome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href = "index.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "post_form.css" rel = "stylesheet">

<!-- Editor for Content Field -->
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/1.0.0-alpha.2/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

  </head>
```

form part:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
   <label for="post_content" class="text_side">Content:</label>
   <br>
   <!-- id for using Editor -->
   <textarea class="form-control" name="" rows="10" cols="30" id="editor" required></textarea>
</div>
```

bottom part:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Javascript-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- CKEditor -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckedit.js"></script>
```

my css:

```
.text_side
{
  float: left;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

my javascript(only the ckeditor activate code):

```
ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
```

Doesn't know why those issues exist, hope can get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more div with id="ckeditor_bar", then put textarea with id="editor" inside div...

https://jsfiddle.net/c298oqhw/17/

Add to css:

```
#ckeditor_bar 
{
     background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! That's work!! I used this to solve the text-align part which also be fixed :)